# How do I get single index value from an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to store a member data in the session variable, but I only want to get the Id index in the member session.

```
console.log(req.session.member);
```

when I set the code to print member session, the debug console return:

> Object {Name: "XXX", password: "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70",account: "XXX", Id: 1}

How do I get single Id index's value from this objec t?

I think that it is an easy problem to solve, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Did you try accessing the `Id` property?

Comment: req.session.member.id

Comment: @Mihai - `Id` has a leading capital... `req.session.member.Id`

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but the debug console prints "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined" error.

Comment: This is an Object with "key-value pairs", where the key is on the left of the colon and the value is on the right .... is your question, 'How do I get the value of a key in an object?"? 

`var obj = {i : 1};`
`console.log(obj.i)` prints 1

Comment: Can you explain your answer with my code?

Comment: Try `console.log(req.session.member ? req.session.member.Id : 'Member session is empty')`. `req.session.member` might be undefined in some cases, so you can't access it's `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

simply assign a varaible to req.session.member and access data from tha var.

var temp = req.session.member

console.log(temp.Id)